# Efficient way to insert data frame from R to SQL

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc

I have a data frame with 10 million rows and 5 columns that I want to insert to an existing sql table. Note that I do not have permission to create a table, I can only insert values into an existing table. I'm currently using RODBCext

```
query_ch <- "insert into [blah].[dbo].[blahblah] 
               (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
               values (?,?,?,?,?)"

sqlExecute(channel, query_ch, my_data)
```

This takes way too long (more than 10 hours). Is there a way accomplish this faster?

Comment: This is not a R specific issue: importing data through many single mysql statements is just damn slow. If available to you, the fastest way might be to write your data to a csv file and use the commandline tool `mysqlimport` or the `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax. Another strategy to gain speed would be to lock the table before importing the data...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `LOAD DATA INFILE` is one order of magnitude faster than multiple `INSERT` statements, which are themselves one order of magnitude faster than single `INSERT` statements.

I benchmark below the three main strategies to importing data from R into Mysql:

1. **single `insert` statements**, as in the question:

   `INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (1,2,3)`
2. **multiple `insert` statements**, formated like so:

   `INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)`
3. **`load data infile` statement**, i.e. loading a previously written CSV file in `mysql`:

   `LOAD DATA INFILE 'the_dump.csv' INTO TABLE test`

---

I use `RMySQL` here, but any other mysql driver should lead to similar results. The SQL table was instantiated with:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `col1` double, `col2` double, `col3` double, `col4` double, `col5` double
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

The connection and test data were created in `R` with:

```
library(RMySQL)
con = dbConnect(MySQL(),
                user = 'the_user',
                password = 'the_password',
                host = '127.0.0.1',
                dbname='test')

n_rows = 1000000 # number of tuples
n_cols = 5 # number of fields
dump = matrix(runif(n_rows*n_cols), ncol=n_cols, nrow=n_rows)
colnames(dump) = paste0('col',1:n_cols)
```

---

**Benchmarking single `insert` statements:**

```
before = Sys.time()
for (i in 1:nrow(dump)) {
  query = paste0('INSERT INTO test (',paste0(colnames(dump),collapse = ','),') VALUES (',paste0(dump[i,],collapse = ','),');')
  dbExecute(con, query)
}
time_naive = Sys.time() - before
```

=> this takes about **4 minutes** on my computer

---

**Benchmarking multiple `insert` statements:**

```
before = Sys.time()
chunksize = 10000 # arbitrary chunk size
for (i in 1:ceiling(nrow(dump)/chunksize)) {
  query = paste0('INSERT INTO test (',paste0(colnames(dump),collapse = ','),') VALUES ')
  vals = NULL
  for (j in 1:chunksize) {
    k = (i-1)*chunksize+j
    if (k <= nrow(dump)) {
      vals[j] = paste0('(', paste0(dump[k,],collapse = ','), ')')
    }
  }
  query = paste0(query, paste0(vals,collapse=','))
  dbExecute(con, query)
}
time_chunked = Sys.time() - before
```

=> this takes about **40 seconds** on my computer

---

**Benchmarking `load data infile` statement**:

```
before = Sys.time()
write.table(dump, 'the_dump.csv',
          row.names = F, col.names=F, sep='\t')
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'the_dump.csv' INTO TABLE test"
dbSendStatement(con, query)
time_infile = Sys.time() - before
```

=> this takes about **4 seconds** on my computer

---

Crafting your SQL query to handle many insert values is the simplest way to improve the performances. Transitioning to `LOAD DATA INFILE` will lead to optimal results. Good performance tips can be found in [this page of mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html).