# Error while copying data frame to Impala database

Tags: r, impala

I am trying to copy my dataframe results to Impala DB. But I am getting error while doing so.

```
library(RJDBC)
library(implyr)
drv <- JDBC("com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver","/User/ImpalaJDBC41.jar",identifier.quote="`")      
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "username/password")

RJDBC::dbWriteTable(conn, 'default.segments', df)
```

I get below error.

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate ([Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:
...ents (id DOUBLE PRECISION,eventdate VARCH...
                         ^
Encountered: IDENTIFIER
Expected: BLOCK_SIZE, COMMENT, COMPRESSION, DEFAULT, ENCODING, INTERMEDIATE, LOCATION, NOT, NULL, PRIMARY, COMMA

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
), Query: CREATE TABLE default.segments (id DOUBLE 
PRECISION,eventdate VARCHAR(255),segment INTEGER).)
```

Assuming something is wrong with datatypes. I have created table by specifying the datatypes and then inserting values to the DB.

```
RJDBC::dbSendUpdate(conn, paste("CREATE TABLE default.segments (id bigint,eventdate timestamp, segment bigint)",";"))

state1 <- paste0("INSERT INTO default.segments VALUES (", apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ",")), ")" )
RJDBC::dbSendUpdate(conn, state1)
```

and this also gives me error with related to datatypes.

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate ([Cloudera] 
[ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, 
SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, 
errorMessage:AnalysisException: Target table 
'default.segments' is incompatible with source expressions.
Expression '2016 - 5 - 29' (type: BIGINT) is not compatible with column 
'eventdate' (type: TIMESTAMP)
), Query: INSERT INTO default.segments VALUES (      3,2016- 
05-29, 79).)
```

below is the structure of my dataframe.

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   19065 obs. of  3 variables:
$ id: num  3 3 3 69 102 102 102 102 102 102 ...
$ eventdate: Date, format: "2016-05-29" ...
$ segment: int  79 76 76 18 11 15 7 11 7 11 ...
```

In the last error it says `Expression '2016 - 5 - 29' (type: BIGINT) is not compatible with column 
    'eventdate' (type: TIMESTAMP)` but my date column in dataframe is of `Date` format. Then what could be the issue? Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates should be provided in quotes. You may transform the column before inserting:

```
df$eventdate <- paste0("'", df$eventdate, "'")
```

or, alternatively,

```
df$eventdate <- sQuote(df$eventdate)
```

otherwise it is recognized as an integer type instead.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I tried with this `RJDBC::dbSendUpdate(conn, state1)` statement and it initially uploaded only first row of my dataframe so I updated my code using `lapply(state1, function(x) RJDBC::dbSendUpdate(conn, x))`. But this is taking huge amount of time to upload my dataframe which has 1.9 million rows and 3 columns. Any suggestions for a better way to upload whole dataframe easily.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43900094/8508149)  answer might be helpful regarding  efficiency (a similar mysql case)