# Exporting data from R to MYSQL server

Tags: mysql, r

```
df <- data.frame(category = c("A","B","A","D","E"),
                 date = c("5/10/2005","6/10/2005","7/10/2005","8/10/2005","9/10/2005"),
                 col1 = c(1,NA,2,NA,3),
                 col2 = c(1,2,NA,4,5),
                 col3 = c(2,3,NA,NA,4))
```

I have to insert a data frame that is created in R to mysql server.

I have tried these methods([Efficient way to insert data frame from R to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881694/efficient-way-to-insert-data-frame-from-r-to-sql)). However, my data also has NA which are fails the whole process of exporting.

Is there a way around to faster upload to data.

```
dbWriteTable(cn,name ="table_name",value = df,overwrite=TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

The above works but is very slow to upload

The method that I have to use is this :

```
before = Sys.time()
chunksize = 1000000 # arbitrary chunk size
for (i in 1:ceiling(nrow(df)/chunksize)) {
  query = paste0('INSERT INTO dashboard_file_new_rohan_testing (',paste0(colnames(df),collapse = ','),') VALUES ')
  vals = NULL
  for (j in 1:chunksize) {
    k = (i-1)*chunksize+j
    if (k <= nrow(df)) {
      vals[j] = paste0('(', paste0(df[k,],collapse = ','), ')')
    }
  }
  query = paste0(query, paste0(vals,collapse=','))
  dbExecute(cn, query)
}
time_chunked = Sys.time() - before
```

Error Encountered:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Unknown column 'NA' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Please include some sample data which you are trying to upload, including rows with `NA`.

Comment: Added the data. See the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the fastest ways to load data into MySQL is to use its `LOAD DATA` command line tool.  You may try first writing your R data frame to a CSV file, then using MySQL's `LOAD DATA` to load it:

```
write.csv(df, "output.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Then from your command line, use:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'output.csv' INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Note that this assumes the CSV file is already on the same machine as MySQL.  If not, and you have it still locally, then use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` instead.

You may read [MYSQL import data from csv using LOAD DATA INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127529/mysql-import-data-from-csv-using-load-data-infile) for more help using `LOAD DATA`.

**Edit:**

To deal with the issue of `NA` values, which should represent `NULL` in MySQL, you may take the approach of first casting the entire data frame to text, and then replacing the `NA` values with empty string.  `LOAD DATA` will interpret a missing value in a CSV column as being `NULL`.  Consider this:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df[is.na(df)] <- ""
```

Then, use `write.csv` along with `LOAD DATA` as described above.

Comment: The above method is efficient. However, this is not able to solve the NULL handling issue. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data". I need to explicitly mention the columns which have may have NULL values.

Comment: @Let'sCode Check the updated answer for one way to workaround your problem with `NA` values in R.